# After Ajax authorization, cart is cleared

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

on the checkout page, I have an authorization form that authorizes via ajax. And after authorization, the cart is cleared, here is the authorization code

```
            $user = get_users([
                'meta_key' => 'phone_number',
                'meta_value' => $tel,
            ]);
            if(!empty($user) && is_array($user)) $user = $user[0];
            else $user = false;

            if($user) {
                nocache_headers();
                wp_clear_auth_cookie();
                wp_set_current_user($user->ID);
                wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID, true);

                echo json_encode(['success' => true, 'user' => [
                    'name' => $user->nickname,
                    'email' => $user->user_email,
                    'tel' => $tel,
                ]]);
                die;
             }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WooCommerce cart is associated with the user's session. When you login a user programmatically via AJAX, the user's session change, leading to the cart being cleared.

You can recreate the cart after successful authorization, try this code:

```
if ($user) {
    nocache_headers();
    wp_clear_auth_cookie();
    wp_set_current_user($user->ID);
    wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID, true);

    // Get cart contents before authorization
    $cart_contents = WC()->cart->get_cart();

    // Clear the cart
    WC()->cart->empty_cart();

    // Recreate the cart for the authenticated user
    foreach ($cart_contents as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
        $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
        $quantity = $cart_item['quantity'];

        // Add product back to the cart
        WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, $quantity);
    }

    echo json_encode(['success' => true, 'user' => [
        'name' => $user->nickname,
        'email' => $user->user_email,
        'tel' => $tel,
    ]]);
    die;
 }
```

Haven't tested this code myself!

Comment: This could work with a regular woocommerce, but I have the woocommerce_bookings plugin installed, and the cart element is not a product, but another type of wc_booking post

Comment: @fsgdoterr Yes, I've provided you with a sample idea based on the regular WooCommerce behaviour. You can explore the WooCommerce Bookings documentation to understand how to handle user sessions, authorization, and cart interactions with bookings.

Comment: This working:)

                    $cart = WC()->session->get('cart');

                    nocache_headers();
                    wp_clear_auth_cookie();
                    wp_set_current_user($user->ID);
                    wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID, true);

                    WC()->session->set('cart', $cart);